# Constrains in Foreign keys using database migrations

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, database-migration

i cant figure out what im doing wrong, but everything looks ok, is giving me this errroof

```
Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed
```

on my migrations, but i dont see any issue.

Migration table 1:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('candidate_industries', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');

            $table->integer('candidate_id')->unsigned();

            $table->foreign('candidate_id')->references('id')->on('candidates');

            $table->integer('industry_id')->unsigned();

            $table->foreign('industry_id')->references('id')->on('industries');
        });
    }
```

Migration number 2:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('candidate_regions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');

            $table->integer('candidate_id')->unsigned();

            $table->foreign('candidate_id')->references('id')->on('candidates');

            $table->integer('region_id')->unsigned();

            $table->foreign('region_id')->references('id')->on('regions');


        });
    }
```

Comment: Please check your order of execution of migration files. Table with foreign key column can't be created before table to which it references.

Comment: Its not my case, the tables im refering already created

Comment: Better to post code for `candidates`, `industries`, and also mention the execution sequence that could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was because "candidates" id column had a different dataType set, in my case was BigInt when i was trying to create a relation with a column of int.